# Cannot insert data from locally hosted app to Appharbor MySQL database ( Timeout exception)

Tags: asp.net, mysql, database, appharbor

I uploaded images to a local database from a locally hosted app. It worked fine!

I tried uploading it to an Appharbor MySQL database and I'm getting the following error.

( connection settings are fine. I have tested insertion with sample string and numbers )

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.TimeoutException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)   at MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at MyNetworkStream.HandleOrRethrowException(Exception e)   at MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int32& insertedId)   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int32& insertedId)   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.HandleTimeoutOrThreadAbort(Exception ex)   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()   at Healthcare.WebForm1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\BOSE\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Healthcare\Healthcare\careSeekersUI.aspx.cs:line 43

What should I do?

Comment: How did you try to upload the data? Please post some code for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should increase the [CommandTimeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-commandtimeout) or use a something other than a webform to insert the data ([MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) comes to mind).

Comment: I haven't installed the Workbench. All I have from Appharbor is the connection string. Is there anyway I could add more parameters to the connection string to increase the timeout time?

Comment: The link says:MySQL currently does not support any method of canceling a pending or executing operation. All commands issues against a MySQL server will execute until completion or exception occurs.

Comment: Okay I tried with a better internet connection. Its fine now :-)